# How to remove CRLF character (Carriage Return Line Feed) in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, terminal, newline

I am receiving a simple output from an Oracle Database, for some reason the output goes down to a new line and I cannot remove that return character.

This is what I've already tried:

```
sed 's/^M//g'
sed 's/\r//g'
sed 's/\n//g'
sed 's/\r\n//g'
sed 's/\r$//'
tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile
sed -i.bak 's/\r$//g' <filename>
sed 's/\r$//g'
```

I then tried `dos2unix` but still nothing...

---

By converting the output in hexadecimal I can see that the misterious character is actually a CRLF, but none of the previous "CRLF removing" solutions seem to work.

- The normal output

[image: The normal output]

- The output converted in hexa

[image: The output converted in hexa]

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: For example `sed 's/\r$//' file` worked just fine over here. Or `awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' file`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @JamesBrown . I already tried both of these solutions, as mentioned in the question, but the character still remains and the output goes to a new line.
EDIT: just read the edit of your comment, I'll try the awk version now!

Comment: What does the `file` command say about the file, as there are `Ã§`s in there. Maybe your locale is messing with you? Maybe something like `LC_ALL=C sed 's/\r//g' file` would work? Or `LC_ALL=C awk ...` because awk might fail `sub` if there are locale incompatible chars in the string to convert and forcing the `LC_ALL=C` might fix it.

Comment: The `file` command says: **UTF-8 Unicode text**. I feel like the reply from @choroba might be the solution, but I need to transform the right characters into bytes. Using sed 's/\x0d\x0a//g' is not removing the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the CRLF bytes, it's much easier in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\x0d\x0a//g'
```

Or you can run `sed` and `tr`:

```
sed 's/\r$//' file | tr -d '\n'
```

`C2 A7` in UTF-8 corresponds to `U+00A7` or `SECTION SIGN` in unicode.

Specify both bytes to sed to remove it:

```
sed 's/\xc2\xa7//g'
```

Comment: Thank you @choroba! This might do the trick! Only question: I would like to remove the 0D 0A character. How can I translate these two in UTF-8 like you did? (The § is actually a delimiter that I set for other purposes)

Comment: @Lorenzo: `perl -pe 's/\x0d\x0a//g' `maybe? The newline is much harder to remove in sed.

Answer (score 3):

To delete all line feed and carriage return characters:

```
tr -d '\r\n' < old > new
```

Any POSIX tr can also take octals:

```
tr -d '\015\012' < old > new
```